# Point selection inside buffer

Tags: qgis, r

I'm working in a case-control study and I would like to ask if it's possible to create a 1km buffer for all cases and select only those ones which at least have one control inside the buffer.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS you could use the Distance matrix and then filter the result to show only sites that are 1000m or below.

Ensure you use the Standard distance matrix and 2 target points.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt, it was very helful. I'm not sure about the units of the distance matrix though because the results in the matrix are different than the measure line :/

Comment: That's odd as it worked perfectly for me. Do they differ by a lot?

Comment: Did this answer your question though?